# ApexCharts: Problem with data labels positioning

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I've been testing out the ApexCharts library through Angular and I am currently facing an issue.

I've created a mixed graph featuring two line series and I have loaded in some dummy data to see how it looks.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, some of the data labels cannot be read because they are overlapping.

Is there a way to set a different dataLabel offset for each series so that this problem does not occur?

If not, any other ideas to solve the issue? This happens in any mixed chart I create (area-area, etc.)

Here is the related code:

```
dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        offsetY: -5,
        textAnchor: "middle",
        background: {
          padding: 7,
          opacity: 0.8,
        },
      }
```

Comment: Hi @John, did you able to resolve it? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hi @John, did you able to resolve it?